# gfortran returns f(x) = x when return value is not set

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I was using a simple program to compute sinc(x) but forgot to set a return value. gfortran did not complain and the return value is x and not zero. kind of scary ....

Here is my program

```
implicit none 
real :: sinc, x
x = 2.0
print *,'x-sinc(x) ',x,sinc(x)
stop 
end

real function sinc(x)
implicit none
real, intent(in) :: x
real :: p
if(abs(x) > 1.e-10) then
  p = sin(x)/x 
else 
  p = 1.0
endif
return
end
```

Again, for any value of x, sinc(x)  returns x. I compiled it with no optimization.

Comment: If you don't define the function result then your program isn't a Fortran program.  We can't blame the compiler for not behaving in given way in that case.  Are you asking: how can I make gfortran complain, or how can I make the return value 0?

Comment: Well, both I guess. If undefined, I would hope it would return 0 not x.

Comment: It would appear that your compiler options are not strict enough. At the end of the day, compiler vendors can only implement the standard as it's written;. If the standard doesn't consider this a fatal error and otherwise doesn't define the behavior, it's left to the compiler vendor to make something up. This is a problem with the language standard, not the compiler; contrast with a language like Ada which made eliminating language ambiguity a design goal.

Comment: Many compilers have excellent options for this kind of thing. Ultimately, though, if you want to be coddled, I recommend a different language.

Comment: `gfortran -Wall prog.f90` returns a message `Warning: Return value of function 'sinc' at (1) not set`. Running returns random garbage for sinc(x) as expected for me (version 4.8.4). There's no reason to have expected this program to have returned zero.